# Bottle - how to get 'instant' information from html?

Tags: python, bottle

Ok, not the best title ever. To better explain it, let me break this into three parts:

I) I can use request.forms.get() if the data I want was in the form that sent me to my actual route, like:

```
@route('/login')
def login():
    return '''
        <form action="/login1" method="post">
            <input name="course" type="text"/>
            <input value="Click!" type="submit"/>
        </form>

@route('/login1')
def add_course():
    course = request.forms.get('course')
```

II) When writing a template, I can pass data from python to html:

```
% k = ['a', '1', 'b']
<h1> {{k}} </h1>
```

III) My question is: it is probably not possible to get instant data from html to python, since the template is 'compiled' (most certainly not the best way to describe it, sorry) and the resulting html in the browser doesn't even know what python has done (there's just html coding in the final source code). So, is there any other way around ? Basically what I want to do is a 'dynamic one-URL site', without needing to be swapping from ../login to ../login1. Something like:

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="course">
% if input == 'Yes':
    [do something]
</body>
```

Basically what jquery would do.

Comment: I've never used bottle, but it seems you're describing behavior similar to AJAX - you need dynamic updates without repeated server calls.

Comment: You are probably going to need to look into AJAX, JSON and maybe some sort of JS front-end framewrok.

Comment: Well, you say "basically what jQuery would do": in fact, it is *exactly* what jQuery would do, since you would use jQuery (or other JS code) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSGIServer + Bottle to create a WebSocket server that would achieve this. Since Bottle is hooked into WSGIServer (in this case), they are working in concert to deliver the static HTML file as well as pass events around that result in real-time data being delivered from Python to the HTML/template page and the reverse as well. You can see an example of doing this here:

https://github.com/jameswomack/CirroSockets

You can listen for an event in the client-side, and trigger events from your Python code—and vice a versa. You can see further information about how you might achieve this at the following pages:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-websocket/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications